# Can't use Stylus @import with Rake Pipeline

Tags: asset-pipeline, stylus

I have a simple Rake Pipeline setup that does nothing more than run "stylus" on my .styl files, using the rake-pipeline-web-filters gem. (The original pipeline does much more, but I've trimmed it down to the essentials for this question.

```
=== Assetfile ===
require "rake-pipeline-web-filters"

output "build"

input "app/style" do
  # Compile Stylus to CSS
  match "*.styl" do
    stylus
  end
end
```

This works fine for converting individual .styl files to individual .css files.

However, I am not able to use the Stylus @import command to import one file in another (necessary for mixins, among other things. Instead I get the error

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: stylus:1
 > 1| @import "appmixins"
   2| 

failed to locate @import file appmixins.styl
```

All the styl files are in the same folder, and when I execute stylus on the commandline using the npm version, the import works fine, so there's no syntax error.

Is this just something that's missing from the Stylus Filter in rake-pipeline-web-filters, or is there something I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like when I run the in Rake Pipeline in assumes all paths are starting from the directory I'm running the pipeline in, and so all the @imports have to be relative to that. Changing my imports to `@import "app/style/appmixins"` worked. This is different from what the NPM version of Stylus does, since it expects (and the docs specify) that all the paths are relative to the individual stylesheets. Not sure if I could have specified the block differently in the Assetfile to make this work as expected, but no matter, it all works for me now.